# Git not allowing unrelated histories

Tags: git, git-branch, pull-request, git-history

In order to have a *clean history* I create an *empty branch* using this command:

```
git checkout --orphan t0
```

then I did the first commit:

```
git commit -m "First commit"
```

The t0 has all the code of development branch now and is identical (source code wise)

After finishing my work I tried pull request but I got error that unrelated histories cannot be used in pull request.

I tried to merge it in development branch by doing this:

```
git merge development --squash --allow-unrelated-histories
```

But I get this message:

```
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
```

Can anyone guide me how to fix the issue and get my code into development?

Comment: Can you explain what is your intention with this single commit branch ? Do you want to remove your repo's history, and use this branch as the starting point for future development ?

Comment: yes, precisely. think of it as a new starting point. so there is this snap shot. **where it all ended previously** in one single commit _which is what I'm trying to do_ and then my commits which are about the new work I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

Git did precisely what you told it too. The merge went well (it even says so in the output). It didn't commit the merge because that's how a squash merge works:

> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), **but do not actually make a commit**

Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

You just need to commit the staged files. To perform a normal merge just remove the `--squash` flag.

In your case I would not recommend a squash merge. A normal merge will produce a commit with two parents to reflect the fact you merged two histories together.

Comment: why would you not recommend it in my case?

Comment: @SimpleFellow: because a squash merge does not create a merge commit. Having a merge commit makes future merges easier, especially if you need to continually merge unrelated histories together.

Comment: ok, I'm not an expert. you mean to say i do a regular merge? but then it will bring back all the history that i want to avoid.

Comment: @SimpleFellow: do you need to merge repeatedly or just once? If you need only merge once, then just commit the staged files and be done with it. Otherwise you will definitely want a non-squash merge so future merges do not require you to resolve previously solved merge conflicts.